# Проблема с декодированием ответа от WebSocket. C#

Tags: c#, websocket

Есть сервер на С# и клиент на скрипте. Данные от сервера отправляются хорошо, а вот с приемом разобраться не могу

Со стороны серера:
`SCRascodirovat(socket.Receive(bytes))`

```
    static string SCRascodirovat(int get)
    {
        String data = null;
        data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, get);
        return data;
    }
```

Со стороны клиента:

```
socket.send("123");
```

Вместо данных от клиента приходит всякая лобуда, хотя с отправкой сообщения клиенту проблем нет и ответное рукопожатие проходит стабильно. Я понимаю что проблема в декодировании сообщения, но не понимаю как правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Уверены, что UTF-8 кодировка ? Попробуйте другие варианты, доступные классу Encoding. Также проблема может быть в неполном получении байтов сообщения либо коротком (либо избыточном, с лишними байтами) буфере байт-массива, в который ведется прием.

Если используется асинхронный прием-передача, то вот кусок кода на асинхронный прием. В `strcontent` хранится полученная строка.

```
 public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {


            try
            {

            _clientSocket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            buffer = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            _clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceivedCallback), null);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка: {0}", e.ToString());
            }

        }

        private void ReceivedCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
            int received = _clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

                if (received ==0)
                {
                    return;
                }
            Array.Resize(ref buffer, received);
            strcontent = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            Array.Resize(ref buffer, _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            refreshMethod(strcontent);
            _clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceivedCallback), null);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Синхронный  сервер пишу, пример ничего нового по проблеме не дал*=(

Comment: @chall2 уверены, что UTF-8 кодировка ? Попробуйте другие варианты, доступные классу Encoding. Также проблема может быть в неполном получении байтов сообщения либо коротком буфере байт-массива, в который ведется прием.

Comment: @chall2 а еще лучше, советую пересаживаться на WCF, ибо сокеты довольно геморройная и старая вещь. Сам уже пересел, нарадоваться не могу :)

Comment: Да, разные кодивки пробовал, но суть в том что ответ приходит одной и той же длинны с разными символами, на один и тот же запрос `socket.send("123");`. В зависимости от длинны запроса`(send(""))` меняется длинна полученного сообщения т.е данные являются "настоящими".

Comment: Спасибо вам, проблема была в том что перезаписывал массив байт и там оставались лишние данные.

Comment: @chall2 пожалуйста, чем смог, как говорится :) Оформлю в ответе наводку.